# Basic URL Rewrite Problem in PHP (mod_rewrite)

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In my .htaccess, I have the following

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^users/?$   users.php
RewriteRule ^users/([a-z]+)/?$   users.php?username=$1
```

Everything works as intended if I do

```
http://example.com/users/
http://example.com/users/joeschmoe/
```

and PHP will read "joeschmoe" as the value for

```
 $_GET['username']
```

However, if I do

```
http://example.com/users/joeschmoe/?foo
```

PHP will not pick up

```
 $_GET['foo']
```

Any idea why this is happening and how I can get it work? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for the "QSA" option to [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) :

> **'`qsappend|QSA`' (query string append)**
>   
> This flag forces the rewrite
>   engine to append a query string part
>   of the substitution string to the
>   existing string, instead of replacing
>   it. Use this when you want to add more
>   data to the query string via a rewrite
>   rule.

That page also states :

> **Modifying the Query String**
>
> By default, the query string is passed
>   through unchanged.  
> You can,
>   however, create URLs in the
>   substitution string containing a query
>   string part. Simply use a question
>   mark inside the substitution string to
>   indicate that the following text
>   should be re-injected into the query
>   string. 
> When you want to erase an
>   existing query string, end the
>   substitution string with just a
>   question mark.  
> **To combine new
>   and old query strings, use the `[QSA]`
>   flag.**

In your case, something like this should do :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^users/?$   users.php
RewriteRule ^users/([a-z]+)/?$   users.php?username=$1 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 6):

Add `[QSA]` option to your [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), which will enable apache to append query string to redirected url:

```
RewriteRule ^users/?$   users.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^users/([a-z]+)/?$   users.php?username=$1 [QSA]
```